# Cairo-Dock recognizes App when starting after App, but not other way round

Tags: 16.04, cairo-dock

I installed Cairo-Dock and Spotify on Xenial. 
When I start Spotify from Cairo-Dock it is not shown as active (if I click the icon again, another Spotify instance starts).
When I start Spotify **before** Cairo-Dock, it **is** shown as active!

I started Cairo-Dock both with and without OpenGL. No idea what else to try ...

Anyone? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and I messed around with it until it worked (kind of....). So, what you have to do is:

-Drag a spotify icon into the dock to create a new launcher.

-Right-click it, go to spotify, then Edit.

-Edit the "Comand to launch on click" to "spotify --mu".

-Apply.

now exit any running spotify session and start it again using the launcher on the dock and it should recognise it.

This is a work around and not a solution to the problem. And as such, there are downsides to it:

-cairo-dock does not recognise any instance of spotify if it was not run using the command "spotify --mu", which means either started using the new launcher, or in a terminal using "spotify --mu".

-It will, randomly, not recognise some instances of spotify. If that happens, just exit spotify and run it again.

I'll play around with it some more and update the answer if I found a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for necroing, but I've found a workaround that might help a poor soul who stumbles upon this thread.

Like Bas Jam said, cairo-dock only recognizes a running spotify instance if it was already running when cairo-dock is started. This workaround basically runs a script that kills Cairo-Dock, starts Spotify, then restarts Cairo-Dock. We'll then set the Spotify launcher icon to run this script.

1. Create a bash script (e.g. spotify-workaround.sh) and place it somewhere (I put mine in ~/.config/cairo-dock/)
2. Paste this into the bash script, then save:

```
#!/bin/sh 
spotify &
killall cairo-dock;
cairo-dock;
```

3. Chmod the script (`chmod +x /path/to/spotify-workaround.sh`)
4. In the launcher options (see Bas Jam's answer) set "Command to launch on click" to `/path/to/spotify-workaround.sh` and hit 'Apply'
5. Now, when you click the Spotify icon on Cairo-Dock, the spotify window will appear, cairo-dock will close and reopen with a running instance of spotify recognized!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue as well. I used the solution described on the post made above me, but i modified it so that if a Spotify process was running it only restarted the dock.

```
#!/bin/sh 

if ! pgrep spotify > /dev/null
then
    spotify &
    sleep .5s;
    while ! pgrep spotify > /dev/null
    do
        sleep
    done
    killall cairo-dock;
    cairo-dock
else
    killall cairo-dock;
    cairo-dock;
fi
```

This could have issues since it does have a chance to infinitely loop, but otherwise this is the best solution.